# signout user aws cognito

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I have Integrated AWS SDK in Node.js. I'm following [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminUserGlobalSignOut.html) documentation to do some actions using the SDK. However, I didn't find any method to sign out a user in that documentation. We have `GlobalSignOut` and `AdminUserGlobalSignOut`. But in my case, I want to sign out a user for a particular session only.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you would want a particular session of a user in your Cognito User Pool to terminate, instead of terminating the sessions in all devices.

To achieve this use-case, you can utilize the ForgetDevice[1] and AdminForgetDevice[2] API calls. These API calls make the refresh token associated with a device invalid, and as a result, the app will not be able to refresh new tokens and will force the user to sign-in successfully again.

A code snippet of Cognito's AdminForgetDevice API call in JavaScript is as follows:

```
var params = {
  DeviceKey: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  UserPoolId: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  Username: 'STRING_VALUE' /* required */
};
cognitoidentityserviceprovider.adminForgetDevice(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

For a more detailed explanation on remembering devices in Amazon Cognito, kindly refer to the following AWS Mobile Blog post[3].

## References

[1]. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ForgetDevice.html

[2]. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminForgetDevice.html

[3]. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/tracking-and-remembering-devices-using-amazon-cognito-your-user-pools/

Comment: on the current aws sdk initiateauth method(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_InitiateAuth.html) response elements has devicekey. but when i run the application it returns a null value. therefore i am unable to send it on my logout request using the admin forget device method. can you please help me with this. Thanks.